# R - return position of element in matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Given a matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0  0.0
[2,]   -1  0.8
```

What is the quickest way in R to iterate over the matrix and return the position of all non-zero entries as an index?

Comment: Your question should be "which is the fastest way?" Then it would also answer itself ;)

Comment: I've been chuckling about this "which is the fastest way" joke for two days. I've made it into a blog post I like it so much.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
mat = matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
which(mat !=0, arr.ind = T)
```

Comment: @Cotton: Ramnath's answer added the very used information that there was an addition parameter to which that produces matrix-oriented output. So I didn't see him as agreeing so much as doing a better job of inferring what the OP wanted.

Comment: @DWin Err, isn't that what the `TRUE` in @Ritchie's R code after "or maybe" is doing? Poor form in a teaching environment to not name arguments, but the two Answers are the same.

Comment: @DWin: It's okay, no need to explain.  You obviously love Ramnath more than me.  I won't spend the afternoon sitting in the corner of the office, crying and drawing pictures of upvoted answers.

Answer (score 19):

```
m <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0), nrow = 2)
which(m != 0)
```

or maybe

```
which(m != 0, TRUE)
```