# R Shiny interactive plots - data labels

Tags: shiny

I am plotting two matrices against each other using R Shiny. Both matrices have the same row and column names. When I click on a datapoint I would like the relevant column and row names to appear rather than the coordinates. Here is a sample of the code/data I am using. Thanks!

```
    ui.R

    library(shiny)

    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Matrix Plot"),
        plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"), br(), verbatimTextOutput("info")
    )
     )

    server.R

    library(shiny)

    d <- read.csv("d.csv",h=T, row.names=1)
    e <- read.csv("e.csv",h=T, row.names=1)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

         d_matrix <-reactive({
            as.matrix(d)
            d
          }) 

        e_matrix <-reactive({
            as.matrix(e)
            e
          }) 


            output$plot<-renderPlot({
            plot(d_matrix(),e_matrix())
        }) 

            output$info <- renderText({
            #output row and column names here instead of data coordinates
            paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=",  input$plot_click$y)
            })
    })
```

d =

A B C D

A 0 1 5 4

B 2 0 5 6

C 3 5 0 8

D 4 6 7 0

e =

A  B   C   D

A 0.0 0.1 0.5 0.4

B 0.2 0.0 0.3 0.6

C 0.3 0.5 0.0 0.8

D 0.4 0.6 0.7 0.0

Comment: The key is to use the `nearPoints` function in Shiny which identifies the point that is being clicked. See https://gallery.shinyapps.io/106-plot-interaction-exclude/ for an example of how it is used.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. For the nearPoints function I'm not sure what the xvar and yvar coordinates would be as they are coming from two matrices rather than two columns...

Comment: You'll probably need to collapse the matrix into vectors, form a data frame, get the point x/y, and do a reverse lookup of matrix location as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522134/r-return-position-of-element-in-matrix

Comment: That worked, thanks!